# cakephp zeus server

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having trouble installing a cakephp app onto a hosting company this is running a zeus server. It is working fine on my apache, but for reasons outside of my control I have to transfer it.

I am getting missing controller in the app. I have it in a sub directory called osm

```
Error: Create the class LoginController below in file: app/Controller/LoginController.php
```

I put a rewrite.script in the root of the app, app folder, webroot. This allowed access to the conrollers and the login but all the css, js was missing.

So I uncommented the line in core.php

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

Now I cant get access to the controllers but I do have the css and js now.

Cant see what I am missing from the examples I have seen.

**if I now use index.php in the url it does work
http://www.mydomain.com/osm/index.php/login**

rewrite.script:

```
    # get the document root
    map path into SCRATCH:DOCROOT from /
    # initialize our variables
    set SCRATCH:ORIG_URL = %{URL}
    set SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI = %{URL}

    # see if theres any queries in our URL
    match URL into $ with ^(.*)\?(.*)$
    if matched then
      set SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI = $1
      set SCRATCH:QUERY_STRING = $2
    endif
    RULE_0_END:

    RULE_1_START:
    # prepare to search for file, rewrite if its not found
    set SCRATCH:REQUEST_FILENAME = %{SCRATCH:DOCROOT}
    set SCRATCH:REQUEST_FILENAME . %{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}

    # check to see if the file requested is an actual file or
    # a directory with possibly an index.  don't rewrite if so
    look for file at %{SCRATCH:REQUEST_FILENAME}
    if not exists then
      look for dir at %{SCRATCH:REQUEST_FILENAME}
      if not exists then
        set URL = osm/index.php?q=%{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}
        goto QSA_RULE_START
      endif
    endif

    # if we made it here then its a file or dir and no rewrite
    goto END
    RULE_1_END:

    QSA_RULE_START:
    # append the query string if there was one originally
    # the same as [QSA,L] for apache
    match SCRATCH:ORIG_URL into % with \?(.*)$
    if matched then
      set URL = %{URL}&%{SCRATCH:QUERY_STRING}
    endif
    goto END
    QSA_RULE_END:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Using CakePHP on Zeus](http://www.webwidget.com.au/blog/33-using-cakephp-on-zeus.html)